# Saving xgboost model to hdfs using python

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, xgboost

I need to save XGBoost model to hdfs using python. I've tried to do it using `xgbm.save_model(path_to_hdfs)`
but I got the following error: `src/io.cc:37: Please compile with DMLC_USE_HDFS=1 to use hdfs`

So my question is how to deal with this error? Or maybe there are any other ways to storing the XGBoost models to hdfs by using python script?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to compile xgboost with HDFS support.

To do this you'd need to do something like:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git
cd xgboost
mkdir build
cmake -DDMLC_USE_HDFS=1 ..
make
```

The install the [Python package](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#python-package-installation) and try again.